# Is there a shorter alternative for "Enjoy your meal"?

Tags: expressions

The French have "Bon appetit".

In Belgium and the Netherlands we have "Smakelijk".

Is there a short way to wish someone a good meal in English?

Comment: "Enjoy your meal" is not short enough? Anyway, what ever it is, it is not an exact translation for 'Bon Appetit'. Only restaurant workers ever say any thing like 'Enjoy your meal' (in AmE/culture).

Comment: Or there's the Jewish mother version: "Look at you, you're nothing but skin and bones! What, we cooked. You'll eat."

Comment: I suppose `BAM!` could be used, if you can pull that off.

Comment: In Spanish, they say *provecho*.  When I lived in Argentina, many people asked me for the English equivalent.  Not able to think of one, I taught them to say, "choke and die," when someone began their meal.

Comment: @Snumpy: That might change for other spanish varieties. About Spain, I've always heard "Que aproveche".

Comment: @Alenanno Understood.  I only went to school there with South and Central Americans and had little to no interaction with Spaniards.

Comment: Yeah I thought so :D It's still useful to know other expressions, you never know when they can be useful :)

Comment: The Hebrew equivalent is B'tai Avon.

Comment: The Mexican Spanish version is apparently "buen provecho".

Comment: If a hosting a meal cooked for others, one often will prompt the guest(s) to eat with "Help yourself (yourselves)".

Comment: I have never understood the [human] need to find the shortest equivalents for foreign words. If the original phrase was 2 words, why does it have to translate into 2 words in another language AND mean the same? I think "bon appetit" translates to "good appetite", which sounds silly as it is missing something. I believe English language is not as "lazy" as French, one cannot just drop english words out and assume the message is understood. The best translation would be "I hope you will enjoy this food with great appetite", although it is certainly not the shortest.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Unfortunately, **no**. However, the French phrase *bon appetit* is very widely known, and you can use that as an alternative.

A very informal option would be to say *Dig in!*, though this has the connotation of eating sloppily or in large amounts, and doesn't necessarily carry the idea of enjoying an elegant, modestly portioned meal.

Comment: *Tuck in* is a slightly more elegant-sounding alternative to *dig in*, though still very informal :)

Comment: @psmears, I've never heard "tuck in" used in that context in the US. Is that a UK term?

Comment: Yes, but still informal. The cook or host says it.

Comment: @psmears +1 for “tuck in”. That’s what I always use.

Comment: @BradC: It is certainly used in the UK. I can't speak as to whether it's UK-only though...

Comment: "Tuck in" is also used in Australia but to me it doesn't sound any more "elegant" than "dig in" - it sounds more colloquial.

Answer (score 11):

It is common in US restaurants for serving staff to say, "Enjoy!" upon placement of the meal.

It is also widely disliked and thought to be overly breezy.

Comment: This was the alternative that I was going to mention, and I also agree with your conclusion.

Comment: Funny, I never realized that connotation in `Enjoy!`. Does the same count for `Enjoy your meal`?

Comment: @nico: No, "Enjoy your meal" is sufficiently formal to not grate upon the senses.

Comment: @TheRaven *Why* does it grate upon the senses, though? A hearty “enjoy!”, while informal, sounds much more honest than most stilted phrases in my opinion.

Comment: @Konrad, @The Raven: In American culture (British too?), there is no recognized statement by anyone -at- the meal to say that is similar to 'bon appetit'. That is, whatever 'Enjoy your meal' means, it is not used by anyone at the table, at least none that I know of. ('dig in' mentioned elsewhere is the only recognizably native phrase).

Comment: @Konrad: The phrase "Enjoy!" is used primarily by service staff that are likely to be near the end of a 6 hour shift. The term is a formality similar to "Enjoy the show" at the theater except the people saying it just obviously do not care and need to say it to (hopefully) get a tip. Neither the speaker nor the listener cares at this point. You may as well say, "Here is your food."

Comment: @Konrad: Traditionally, as I've heard the term "enjoy!" critiqued, the problem seems to be that it is delivered as an imperative. The diner may well wonder if there's a choice in the matter. A more complete sentence, "Please enjoy your meal," for example, is a bit softer in that regard.

Comment: @Mitch: You're right. The Japanese have an expression, "itadakimasu," that is usually uttered before every meal by all present (transl. "grateful to recieve this"). Some English speakers say some kind of prayer, but apart of "dig in" we really have no expression that accords with bon appetit.

Comment: That connotation does not exist in the UK.  It's not usual to say anything but "Enjoy!" is a decent alternative, as "Enjoy your meal!" is a bit too wordy imo.

Comment: In Australia there is no negative connotation to "Enjoy!". I always find that Australia is a more egalitarian society than the USA where I find customers treat staff as servants. I've even been "corrected" for thanking the staff! Waitstaff in Australia won't put on a phoney "nice" act to get a larger tip. On the flipside Australians are notoriously stingy at tipping when they're overseas.

Comment: @hippietrail It's helpful to remember that the American minimum wage for food servers is $2.13 vs. $7.15 for other workers who don't get tips.  Anyway the breeziness of 'enjoy' varies for me with the tone of voice/attitude of the server, not in the words.

Comment: @Merk: Yes indeed, all the more reason for customers to be friendly and nice to waitstaff I would think, but the necessity of tipping seems to provide a reason not to be friendly to the staff, at least from an outsider's perspective. Anyway it's getting off-topic.

Answer (score 9):

***Bon appetit*** is best if you want to say something.

Note that in English speaking countries we don't generally express this sentiment at all.

When we do feel like saying something, among native English speakers I feel the anglicised version of the French phrase is the most common way.

I don't believe I've ever heard "enjoy your meal" used among groups consisting only of native English speakers. It is widely used by people learning English and even people teaching English to foreigners. I think it must be in lots of bilingual phrasebooks, dictionaries, and teaching materials.

Everybody who uses "bon appetit" in English perceives it as French but unless they've studied French or spent some time in a French speaking country, it is mostly mispronounced in that we pronounce the final "t" where French speakers do not. (This is ignoring the many other more subtle differences between English and French pronunciation.)

To sum up:

- If you really want to act like a native speaker don't say anything.
- If you still really want to say something and still be like a native say "bon appetit" but pronounce it *bon-app-a-teet*.
- If you're worried about "correct English" say nothing or stick with "enjoy your meal".

Comment: or in the words of Jim Royle "get it et, it all goes to mek the turd"

Comment: Your 3rd paragraph about 'learners' makes a lot of sense. As a native Russian who often meets people learning English here, I've noticed they often seek for this equivalent. Because culturally such phrase is expected due to the existence of a phrase similar to _Bon Appetit_ in Russian (I guess we have a calque from French). The usual phrase which satisfies everyone is _Enjoy your meal_ as it must be suggested in text books and other study materials (I haven't checked). So 90% of learners in Russia I guess think this is the real equivalent.

Comment: +1 for a very good answer. I've done my research but couldn't reach the great conclusion, simple and clear.

Comment: How do native speakers, guests and hosts, act when food is ready to be eaten on a table? I don't they look at each other to see who just starts to eat first?

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't.

This reflects the fact that there is not a custom of saying "bon appetit" or equivalent in the Anglophone world.

Comment: I think the French consider that "bon appetit" before English cooking to be sarcasm!

Comment: @mgb Ouch!That hurts.

Answer (score 2):

How about

> Eat well!

Answer (score 0):

Lol, how much shorter do you want?  "Smakelijk" is 3 syllables (I think). "Bon appetit" is 4 syllables as is "Enjoy your meal".

Comment: @Kevin That’s why the French often (informally) resort to “bon ap’”.

Comment: @Konrad - and why we Americans resort to "Enjoy" which, evidently, is irksome to some people.

Comment: @Kevin, I don't know why; I find "Enjoy" perfectly acceptable. It's all in the delivery.

Comment: But the typical (deep breath) - hello-my-name-is-jane-and-i'll-be-your-server-for-today-let-me-tell-you-about-our-specials- is a lot longer.

Comment: Also, 'smakelijk' is typically preceded by 'eet', so you're back up to 4 syllables again.

Comment: Perhaps in the Netherlands. In Belgium, 90% of the time people stick with "Smakelijk".

Comment: the schwa in "appetit" is usually pronounced very quickly, it barely counts as a syllable

Answer (score 0):

There may be a connection between English (I include Americans) and food. In most other cultures you are expected to enjoy your food. It has been prepared for you with loving care (by mom). In the English-speaking world it is - "there you go!"

Answer (score 0):

I sadly do not have the source for this, but a UK-English etiquette advisor on some low-brow tv program explained it was because you expect the host to have prepared a good meal for you, and wishing him or her a good meal highlights the fact that you had the option open for the contrary: a tasteless and boring forced feeding exercise.

It does sound a bit like a rule made up to conform to current behaviors though.

Answer (score -1):

I do food delivery in a formal work uniform and I was in need to express a word to customers at the moment of handing them their food and leaving (to show some courtesy); so I improvised with the expression "enjoy your food" and noticed people didn't react in accordance. Then I started to use "enjoy it " and still I felt that I was not getting a good response from people, only a silent pause but not a welcome response as from a clear simple and correct expression. I'm replacing the word *food* with "meal"! like *enjoy your meal!* Or limit myself to just saying  *Thank you and good-bye*!  I noticed that simple and clear is accepted better.