# Answer to "enjoy your meal"

Tags: conversation, phrase-requests, politeness

When you're having lunch and you see someone he can say "enjoy your meal", "bon appétit" or  "enjoy". I can answer him by saying "thank you", for instance. But for example in Spanish we usually say a sentence which means something like "you can join me/us, if you want" (inviting him). Is there any typical sentence in English with a similar meaning?

Comment: Related:http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20511/is-there-a-shorter-alternative-for-enjoy-your-meal . Seems English has lack of this kind of dialectics within it.

Comment: @Juanillo - What sentence would that be?  I'd like to use that in conversation sometime.

Comment: @MT_Head It is "Si gustas"

Comment: @Juanillo - Muchas gracias!  (By the way - would you always use "Si gustas", or would you switch to "Si gusta Ud." depending on context?)

Comment: @MT_Head. Both are good, though the second one is much more polite. Though I would use instead of "Si gusta Ud." just "Si gusta" with implicit subject (it sounds much better to me though it's grammatically correct). A more formal way would be "si gusta (Ud.) puede acompañarame/acompañarnos". With a friend you should use just "Si gusta", less formal because the subject is "tú" instead of "Ud." (though all these expression are quite formal indeed).

Comment: @Juanillo - just to clarify, do you mean "With a friend you should use just 'Si **gustas**', less formal because the subject is 'tú'"?

Comment: @MT_Head yes that is. Though it is quite formal even with the subject "tú".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I don't think English has a comparable *common* phrase.

However you could always just ask him if he's interested in joining you.

> Would you like to join me?

or

> Care to join me?

or

> Care to sit down?

Answer (score 4):

Since there is no set phrase/cultural equivalent in English for [Bon Appetit](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20511/is-there-a-shorter-alternative-for-enjoy-your-meal) (you can say "Enjoy your meal", and it would be understood, but it is not what people say' when starting a meal and is pretty uncommon), there is even less likely an accepted reply.

If I were to describe a classic British meal, the appropriate response to something so unexpected would be stony silence and reflection upon ones past sins as though one were climbing the stairs to the gallows. Any more substantive response would get nervous glances and an inner reminder to avoid playing darts with them.

But one could have a smoother, close to literal translation that could work (e.g. something like "Please join us"). It just wouldn't be idiomatic.

Comment: There is an English equivalent for "bon appetit". It is "bon appetit". Just as "rendezvous" is the English equivalent for "rendez-vous" and "garage" is the English equivalent for "garage". It's just at the less anglicized end of the scale. Maybe even a bit tongue in cheek but many of us use it, unlike "enjoy your meal".